# Remove outliers in Pandas dataframe with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of Report Date, Time Interval and Total Volume for a full year. I would like to be able to remove outliers within each Time Interval.

This is as far as I've been able to get...

```
dft.head()

    Report Date Time Interval   Total Volume
5784    2016-03-01  24  467.0
5785    2016-03-01  25  580.0
5786    2016-03-01  26  716.0
5787    2016-03-01  27  803.0
5788    2016-03-01  28  941.0
```

So i calculate the quantile's

```
low = .05
high = .95
dfq = dft.groupby(['Time Interval']).quantile([low, high])
print(dfq).head()

                    Total Volume
Time Interval                   
24            0.05        420.15
              0.95        517.00
25            0.05        521.90
              0.95        653.55
26            0.05        662.75
```

And then I'd like to be able to use them to remove outliers within each Time Interval using something like this...

```
dft = dft.apply(lambda x: x[(x>dfq.loc[low,x.name]) & (x < dfq.loc[high,x.name])], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to filter out as follows:

```
In [11]: res = df.groupby("Date")["Interval"].quantile([0.05, 0.95]).unstack(level=1)

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
             0.05   0.95
Date
2016-03-01  489.6  913.4
```

Now we can lookup these values for each row using `loc` and filter:

```
In [13]: (res.loc[df.Date, 0.05] < df.Interval.values) & (df.Interval.values < res.loc[df.Date, 0.95])
Out[13]:
Date
2016-03-01    False
2016-03-01     True
2016-03-01     True
2016-03-01     True
2016-03-01    False
dtype: bool

In [14]: df.loc[((res.loc[df.Date, 0.05] < df.Interval.values) & (df.Interval.values < res.loc[df.Date, 0.95])).values]
Out[14]:
   Report        Date  Time  Interval  Total Volume
1    5785  2016-03-01    25     580.0           NaN
2    5786  2016-03-01    26     716.0           NaN
3    5787  2016-03-01    27     803.0           NaN
```

*Note: grouping by 'Time Interval' will work the same, but in your example doesn't filter any rows!*

Answer (score 5):

```
df[df.groupby("ReportDate").TotalVolume.\
      transform(lambda x : (x<x.quantile(0.95))&(x>(x.quantile(0.05)))).eq(1)]
Out[1033]: 
      ReportDate  TimeInterval  TotalVolume
5785  2016-03-01            25        580.0
5786  2016-03-01            26        716.0
5787  2016-03-01            27        803.0
```