# Removing outliers using percentile in panda dataframe groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe df

```
Transportation_Mode time_delta  trip_id segmentid   Vincenty_distance   velocity       acceleration       jerk
         walk           1          1        1          1.551676553     1.551676553     0.550163852    -1.017629555
         walk           1          1        1          1.70920675      1.70920675      0.16257622     -0.39166534
         walk           1          1        1          1.871782971     1.871782971    -0.22908912     -0.734438511
         walk          12          1        1          23.16466284     1.93038857      0.324972586    -0.331839143
         walk           1          1        1          5.830059603     5.830059603    -3.657097132     2.614438854
         bus            1         16        5          8.418372046     8.418372046    -7.259019484     7.40735053
         bus           23         16        5          26.66510892     1.159352562     0.148331046    -0.036318522
         bus            1         16        5          4.570966614     4.570966614    -0.68699497     -0.889126918
```

I want to remove outlier values within each group of Transportation_Mode based on percentile values [0.05,0.95]

My problem is similar to discussion [Remove outliers in Pandas dataframe with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104072/remove-outliers-in-pandas-dataframe-with-groupby)

The code I write is

```
res = df.groupby("Transportation_Mode")["Vincenty_distance"].quantile([0.05, 0.95]).unstack(level=1)
df.loc[ (res.loc[ df.Transportation_Mode, 0.05] < df.Vincenty_distance.values) & (df.Vincenty_distance.values < res.loc[df.Transportation_Mode, 0.95]) ]
```

but I get the error, ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. I don't know where I am wrong here.

Complete input data is available at the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JjvS7igTmrtLA4E5Rs5D6tsdAXqzpYqX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if we see,

`(res.loc[ df.Transportation_Mode, 0.05] < df.Vincenty_distance.values) & (df.Vincenty_distance.values < res.loc[df.Transportation_Mode, 0.95])`

returns a series of type `bool` which can be to select rows in original `df`. We just need to give the value of the series for which just add `.values` while giving it to the `df.loc[]`. Below should work:

```
df.loc[ ((res.loc[ df.Transportation_Mode, 0.05] < df.Vincenty_distance.values) & (df.Vincenty_distance.values < res.loc[df.Transportation_Mode, 0.95])).values]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame`, so possible filtering:

```
m1 = (df.Transportation_Mode.map(res[0.05]) < df.Vincenty_distance)
m2 = (df.Vincenty_distance.values < df.Transportation_Mode.map(res[0.95]))

df = df[m1 & m2]
print (df)  
  Transportation_Mode  time_delta  trip_id  segmentid  Vincenty_distance  \
1                walk           1        1          1           1.709207   
2                walk           1        1          1           1.871783   
4                walk           1        1          1           5.830060   
5                 bus           1       16          5           8.418372   

   velocity  acceleration      jerk  
1  1.709207      0.162576 -0.391665  
2  1.871783     -0.229089 -0.734439  
4  5.830060     -3.657097  2.614439  
5  8.418372     -7.259019  7.407351
```