# What's the most efficient way to groupby exclude outlier

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have dataframe like this

```
channel | ID | cnt_txn | amount
   A    |  1 |    3    |  15
   A    |  2 |    5    |  20
   B    |  1 |    4    |  12
   C    |  3 |    3    |  12
   C    |  2 |    10   |  10
```

and I have this function

```
def is_outlier(s):
    lower_limit = s.mean() - (s.std() * 3)
    upper_limit = s.mean() + (s.std() * 3)
    return s.between(lower_limit, upper_limit)
```

What's the easiest and readible way to group by channel and apply `is_outlier`(or similar logic) function to each of the data in the group by channel

I have tried

```
df.groupby(['vertical'])['cnt_txn','amount'].apply(is_outlier)
```

it resulting in

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'between'

I guess that it didn't looped each column in the dataframe

If someone can explain this and provide a solution would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: You want to filter out the outlier by each group by channel right?

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong yes

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104072/remove-outliers-in-pandas-dataframe-with-groupby

Comment: similar to this `df[df.groupby("ReportDate").TotalVolume.\
      transform(lambda x : (x<x.quantile(0.95))&(x>(x.quantile(0.05)))).eq(1)]`, put your logic into `transform` that returns `True` or `False` for each row,

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong I have tried `df[df.groupby(['channel'])['cnt_txn','amount'].transform(lambda x : (x<x.quantile(0.95))&(x>(x.quantile(0.05)))).eq(1)]` and it return me `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4053390 elements, new values have 6809279 elements` something like this

Comment: ok, let me try first,

Comment: hi, only `amount` column affect your outlier, or you want to split outliner by `cnt_txn` too?

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong hi, I thinks I know why its throw error now it's because of the group by transform level. thanks much. I will just use apply instead of transform and use that array to filter the data out

Comment: Hi, if you apply after group by it will give the grouped result, but transform append the data back to original data, depends on your needs. glad I could help, just comment if you encounter any issue

Answer (score 0):

According to As of now knowledge,
Thanks `@Phung Duy Phong` to point out the logic.

the outlier func  should look like this in order to speed up the performance in groupby

```
def is_outlier(x):
    return (x<x.quantile(0.95))&(x>(x.quantile(0.05)))
```

and groupby statement should look like this

```
df[df.groupby(['channel'])['cnt_txn','amount'].apply(is_outlier).eq(1).all(axis=1)]
```

noted that `.eq(1)` come in to simplified the result into `True` and `False` instead of having `Nan` value

and `.all(axis=1)` is to combine the return array into  one dimension stating all column must be `true` to be `true`

and lastly `df[arrayOfTrueFalse]` will return dataframe without outlier